# Creating a specific enough ODE for the cotangent function

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I was attempting to create an ODE for the cotangent function for something I’m working on. I differentiated the cotangent function twice and got a non-linear second order ODE, which is perfect for what I need. The only problem is, the ODE when solved doesn’t give me $\cot(x)$.

So I would like some help from my fellow MSE users to help me figure out what I need to do to make an ODE or multiple ODE’s such that I can make it specific enough to have the answer be $\cot(x)$.

For reference, here is the ODE and my work in solving it:

$$y=\cot(x)$$

$$\dot{y}=-\csc^2(x)$$

$$\ddot{y}=2\csc^2(x)\cot(x)$$

$$\ddot{y}=2y(y^2+1)$$

Now solving it with the appropriate $I.C$ (initial conditions).

$$\ddot{y}=2y(y^2+1)$$

$$I.C: y(\frac{\pi}{2})=0, \dot{y}(\frac{\pi}{2})=0$$

$$\int\ddot{y}\dot{y}\,dx=2\int(y^3+y)\dot{y}\,dx$$

$$\frac{1}{2}(\dot{y})^2=\frac{1}{2}y^4+y^2+C_{1}$$

$$I.C\longrightarrow{C_{1}=0}$$

Rearranging yields:

$$\pm\int\frac{1}{y\sqrt{y^2+2}}\,dy=\int\,dx$$

Now taking a little detour to evaluate the L.H.S integral:

$$I:=\pm\int\frac{1}{y\sqrt{y^2+2}}dy$$

Let $$y=\sqrt{2}\tan(\phi)$$

$$I=\frac{\pm{1}}{\sqrt{2}}\int\frac{\sec(\phi)}{\tan(\phi)}\,d\phi$$

$$I=\frac{\pm{1}}{\sqrt{2}}\int\csc(\phi)\,d\phi$$

$$I=\frac{\pm{1}}{\sqrt{2}}\log|\frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{y^2+2}}{y}|+C_{2}$$

And so

$$\frac{\pm{1}}{\sqrt{2}}\log|\frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{y^2+2}}{y}|+C_{2}=x$$

Also, my initial conditions give me a division be zero that doesn’t seam easily resolved by appealing to limits. I really don’t know what went wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Doesn't the first-order o.d.e. $y' = -\csc^2 x$ already satisfy the condition? (Of course, the solutions are $x \mapsto \cot x + C$.) If you want an autonomous o.d.e., you can use the Pythagorean identity to write $y' = -(1 + y^2)$, the solutions of which are $x \mapsto \cot(x + C)$.

Comment: I want it to be somewhat challenging. That’s the point of creating a non-linear second order equation.

Comment: @Person You should include whatever constraints you want to impose in your question statement, to avoid wasting the time of someone who might write an answer that doesn't interest you.